# How do I count the number of times X appears in multiple columns (with some added challenges)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to make a simple bar graph, but I can't wrap my head around how to clean this data and prep it for graphing.

I want to apply a function to multiple columns in R, but I also want it handle duplicated rows.

Ultimately I want to return a simple data frame that looks like this:

```
Tissue    Number_of_hits
tissue1   3
tissue2   1
tissue3   3
```

I suck at making toy data. Here is my attempt at some

```
df <- data.frame(gene = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D"),
                 tissue1 = sample(x = 0:6, size = 6),
                 tissue2 = sample(x = 0:6, size = 6),
                 tissue3 = sample(x = 0:6, size = 6)
        )

  gene tissue1 tissue2 tissue3
1    A       6       4       6
2    A       3       1       2
3    B       4       6       0
4    C       1       2       3
5    D       5       5       1
6    D       0       0       5
```

So what I want to do is the following:

1. count how many times tissue1 has a gene >= 3.
2. If, for example gene A shows two hits for tissue1 >= 3, only count it as one.
3. If, for example gene D has only one hit, then just count it as one.

The apply function shown below kindof helps here to filter for events that meet my cutoff (here it is .15 instead of 3).

```
for (column in test$tissue1){
  column <- lapply(column, function(counts) if (counts >= 0.15) TRUE else FALSE)
}
```

Obviously my for loop isn't working here and I can't simply reassign the column variable like I would hope to.

I'm pretty stuck here. If someone could shed some light on this please let me know.

Is there a way to use dplyr/tidyverse to solve this?

Comment: In my experience, >90% of problems in the tidyverse are solveable by converting your data into long, "tidy" format using `tidyr::gather(tissue, value, -gene)`. Once you've done that, could use `filter(value >= 3) %>% count(tissue)`

Comment: Quick tip: The toy example is helpful but would be better if you precede it with `set.seed(YOUR_FAVORITE_NUMBER)` so that we can all use the same example data.

Comment: Just as a friendly note, you can also [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data generation statement you provided, I generated this starting data set:

```
  gene tissue1 tissue2 tissue3
1    A       0       1       2
2    A       3       5       3
3    B       2       3       0
4    C       6       4       1
5    D       4       2       6
6    D       5       0       4
```

Then I ran these statements

```
result <- df %>%
    gather(key = "tissue", value = "magnitude", -gene) %>%
    group_by(gene, tissue) %>%
    summarise(hits = sum(magnitude >= 3)) %>%
    group_by(tissue) %>%
    summarise(genehits = sum(hits >= 1))
```

to get this result

```
  tissue  genehits
  <chr>      <int>
1 tissue1        3
2 tissue2        3
3 tissue3        2
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that is perfect. One more tiny issue is the tissue names are not that straightforward. Is there a way to declare the key as a set of columns in gather?

I.E. ```gather(c(2:6), value, -gene)```
throws an error

Comment: @Alex Nesta - I am not quite sure about your question concerning declaring the key as a set of columns in gather. As I understand it, by default, you use key to name a new variable, and the values of that variable are the names of all the columns except those you have excluded by listing them with a "-" (eg as "-gene" in the example above). I'm not sure why you would need to specify the columns as c(2:6).

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood how the function worked. My real data has officially been wrangled :) THANK YOU!